# PHP json_encode fails from https

Tags: php, https, json

My php script fails when served as a secure page and json_encode() is called, but not otherwise. The code is distilled from a larger script called from XHR. PHP Version 5.2.0., Apache/1.3.34 (Unix).

Is the problem source: PHP, my ISP, or me?

To demo, call this script 4-ways:

https://www.camdenac.com/test_json_encode.php?encode=0  => works, secure protocol, does not call json_encode().
https://www.camdenac.com/test_json_encode.php?encode=1  => fails, secure protocol, calls json_encode().

In the first case you will see some html and then php echoes the results.
In the second case you will see only the html; no php output.

```
/*
Try these 2 links also from non-secure protocol.
http://www.camdenac.com/test_json_encode.php?encode=0  => works.
http://www.camdenac.com/test_json_encode.php?encode=1  => works.
*/

<?php
$encode= 0;
if( isset($_GET['encode']) ){
    $encode= substr(trim($_GET['encode']),0,1);
}

$dummy= array(1,2,3,4,5);
$json="We did not call json_encode.";

if($encode){
    $json= json_encode($dummy);
}

echo '<p>IT WORKS!</p>';
echo '<p>Host protocol is: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</p>';
echo '<p>Query string is: '.$_SERVER['argv'][0].'</p>';
echo '<p>HTTPS is: '.$_SERVER['HTTPS'].'</p>';
echo '<p>json encoding is: '.$json.'</p>';
echo '<p>Array dump follows:</p>';

var_dump($dummy);
?>
```

Comment: Define "fails". What happens? Do you get any error? Are you sure both scripts are same? Are you sure PHP versions are same?

Comment: Wait, are the "works,fails" reversed for the last 2 tests?  Did you `var_dump($_GET)`? Do you have any rewrite rules which may be breaking the query string for https requests?

Comment: json_encode doesn't look to have anything to do with it.  How does the contents of $_GET change based off the request URL used?  Maybe cast your $encode as a (bool).

Comment: @SheikhHeera He's echoing `$json` two lines earlier.

Comment: @SalmanA: See my edited notes.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Works,Fails are correct for last two tests. They are clickable links now. I believe I'm capturing the query string correctly.

Comment: @user1919378 But that doesn't make sense that it wouldn't print because it is ont inside any conditional. (if that is the same code as posted above) It should print `IT WORKS` no matter what.  Do you have error_reporting turned on? Are you getting a fatal error?  `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: how is this page loaded into the page you have online?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: I added the error reporting - thanks. I get: "Fatal error: Call to undefined function json_encode() in..."

Comment: @user1919378 There you have it. What PHP version? `json_encode()` is not available before 5.2.something.  Does your server use a different PHP version for HTTPS requests? Sounds like something to discuss with your hosting support. Weird situation....

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: json_encode() is available since PHP 5 >= 5.2.0. We are running 5.2.0.  phpinfo() on the site reports: "Registered PHP Streams: php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.zlib, https, ftps." Wouldn't that suggest we are good to go on http or https?

Comment: @user1919378 That's different. Those are the stream wrappers available for use by things like `fopen()`. This sounds fishier, like the server config is routing HTTPS requests to a different PHP binary entirely.  Add `phpversion()` to your script and test the output with and without https.

Comment: Double check the PHP versions -- both HTTP and HTTPS versions of your website and post the output.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Bingo! https version is 5.1.1.  http version is 5.2.0.  Thanks very much for your help.  I wasted a lot of time on this one.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of php is to old and does not contain the `json_encode` function. You may need to update your php version if you want to use it.